# Creating a Button or Icon to change event

Tags: xcode, ipad, button, colors

Afternoon

I have an iPad App that got rejected - one because I had iPad in the title and the other because I am only using one color in my App, and they would like ot see more.

My App allows me to draws lines on screen with my finger - I can change the color by going into the code, but what I probably need to do is create a couple of buttons that allow the user to change color on screen.

I have no clue as to how to do this - has anyone done anything like this ?

Iain

Answer (score 0):

i would love to help you but you will need to do some learning your self,setting a button is a basic skill but it still requires some knowledge. and i truly advise you to wait a little and learn more before you try to send apps to apple.

but any way, look at the apple example called "GLPaint"
they do there exactly what you are asking by setting a segmented controller that switches the colors of the drawing. focus at the following code taken from apple example. this code is setting the UISegmentedControl (simply a set of buttons):

```
  // Create a segmented control so that the user can choose the brush color.
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red.png"],
                                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Yellow.png"],
                                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"],
                                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue.png"],
                                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Purple.png"],
                                                nil]];

    // Compute a rectangle that is positioned correctly for the segmented control you'll use as a brush color palette
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + kLeftMargin, rect.size.height - kPaletteHeight - kTopMargin, rect.size.width - (kLeftMargin + kRightMargin), kPaletteHeight);
    segmentedControl.frame = frame;
    // When the user chooses a color, the method changeBrushColor: is called.
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changeBrushColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    // Make sure the color of the color complements the black background
    segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    // Set the third color (index values start at 0)
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 2;

    // Add the control to the window
    [window addSubview:segmentedControl];
    // Now that the control is added, you can release it
    [segmentedControl release];
```

after that look at the function the segmented controller is attached to called "changeBrushColor":

```
- (void)changeBrushColor:(id)sender
{
    CGFloat                 components[3];

    // Play sound
    [selectSound play];

    // Define a new brush color
    HSL2RGB((CGFloat)[sender selectedSegmentIndex] / (CGFloat)kPaletteSize, kSaturation, kLuminosity, &components[0], &components[1], &components[2]);
    // Defer to the OpenGL view to set the brush color
    [drawingView setBrushColorWithRed:components[0] green:components[1] blue:components[2]];

}
```

its a fairly simple example, start there and if you will have more questions, ask again and we will try to help.

good luck
shani

Comment: Hi Shani - I looked at the code and have it working quite well. The only thing that I cannot seem to do is place an image behind the colored lines - I have tried lots of different options. When I do see the image, the colored lines dont write on it.

Comment: Hi lain, i would love to help but you better paste a second question for that or add it to your first question so i could paste an other answer.(send me an email [shannoga@me.com] when you do that and i will be able to help you with that to)  BTW, if my first answer helped you, you can click the mark to mark your question as answered. if you do that your (and mine) chances to get answers in the future will be better.